# full calendar truncate title

Tags: fullcalendar, title, truncate, qtip

I am using fullcalendar 1.6.0, with qtip2, building an array in php and using this as the events list

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    events: [
    <?php echo $eventlist; ?>
    ],
```

It is working fine, but I would now like to use the calendar in a 'mobile friendly' layout.

What I want to do is, at resolutions below a certain breakpoint, remove some or all of the event information from displaying within the calendar itself, (so a colored block appears on the calendar, but little or nothing else) but still appear in the qtip.

Can I use `eventrender` to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I think you can do this.
Below is the sample code. You have to use two events eventRender and eventAfterAllRender. or you can also hide the elements inside eventAfterAllRender.

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    if( window.screen.width < 300 ) {
       $('.fc-event-title').hide();
       $('.fc-event-time').hide();
    }
},
eventAfterAllRender: function( view ) {
      $('.fc-event-inner').each(function(){
          $(this).qtip(
          {
              content: $(this).children('.fc-event-time').html() + '' + $(this).children('.fc-event-title').html()
          });
      }
}
```

NOTE: This code is not tested. Change it according to your needs. Something like above will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the (swift) reply.

I couldn't get it working at first, and I'm not sure I am doing it correctly, but this is what I have done.

I edited the existing event render, (which shows the qtip) as follows

  [code]if( $( window ).width() < 760 ) {
 $('.fc-event-title').replaceWith("&nbsp;");
    };[/code]

If I hide the title, i get zero hight event in the calendar, so I replaced it with a non-breaking space instead

I haven't used the eventAfterAllRender function, it seems to work fine without it